# Search variable/item/attribute using STL in c++?

Tags: c++, search, stl, stl-algorithm

There is any way to search an item or attribute  or variable in C++ using STL .
We can use any container of STL providing `Searching time as less as possible` .  Container contains `pair<int,int>` . i would like to search a pair `p(a,x)` which should return all pairs X whose `p.first  == Xi.first and p.second != Xi.second for all i` .
e.g. 
Let container is unordered_set .

```
  unordered_set< pair<int , int > > myset =
  {{1,2},{1,5},{1,6},{2,4},{3,5},{4,6},{6,7},{6,8}};
  if i search for p(1,5) then it should return pair(1,2),(1,6)
  if i search for p(2,4) or (3,5),(6,7) then it should return NULL i.e. nothing
  if i search for p(6,7) then it should return pair(6,8)
```

Comment: Take a `multimap` or `unordered_multimap`; use `equal_range` to find the range with the given key and then iterate through that range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along the lines of

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> 
  find_nonmatching_values(const std::unordered_multimap<int, int> & thing,
                          int key, int value) {
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> ret;
    auto range = thing.equal_range(key);
    std::copy_if(range.first, range.second, std::back_inserter(ret),
                 [value](const std::pair<const int, int> &p) 
                 { return p.second != value; });
    return ret;
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ab30ed4a49c7e607). Templatizing this code is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly more general than T.C.s version:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iterator>

template <typename T, typename InputIterator, typename OutputIterator, typename Comparator>
void find_mismatches(InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
                     T const& val, OutputIterator out, Comparator comp)
{
    for (; first != last; ++first)
    {
        auto&& f = *first;
        if (!comp(f.second, val))
            *out++ = f;
    }
}

template <typename AssociativeCont, typename OutputIterator, typename Comparator>
void find_mismatches(AssociativeCont&& rng, typename std::remove_reference<AssociativeCont>::type::value_type const& val, OutputIterator out, Comparator comp)
{
    auto range = rng.equal_range(val.first);
    find_mismatches(range.first, range.second, val.second, out, comp);
}

template <typename AssociativeCont, typename OutputIterator>
void find_mismatches(AssociativeCont&& rng, typename std::remove_reference<AssociativeCont>::type::value_type const& val, OutputIterator out)
{
    auto range = rng.equal_range(val.first);
    find_mismatches(range.first, range.second, val.second, out, std::equal_to<decltype(val.second)>());
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8747882ce0827235). Note that you could still expand this by using a template parameter that is a pointer-to-member to a `value_type`'s member.